# WP Function echo a $var in Array

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to echo a $var in a function array in WP. I need to have a field on the Woocommerce checkout (accomplished) with a VALUE from a $_SESSION. The checkout field looks like this:

```
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
public function VAT_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

            $fields['billing']['VAT_cui'] = array(
            'label'     => __('Dom&aelig;ne', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder'   => _x('Intet Valgt', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required'  => false,
            'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
            'clear'     => true,
                            'type'        => 'select',
                            'options'     => array(
                            'kobdomain' => __('echo $MYVAR', 'woocommerce' ),
                            )
            );

            return $fields;
                            }
```

I understand i doesnt work, but im stuck :(

Problem is i need the return $fields input value to be filled with a string from my Session. I think its possible with the SELECT OPTION field, but as you can see, i dunno how to echo value in it.

Comment: Doesn't `__( $MYVAR, 'woocommerce' )` work ?

Comment: No, it just returns a empty field - Nothing in the OPTION

Comment: I really appreciate any suggestions or help, because i have a deadline to fix this issue :(